# I am getting problem when using tailwind with react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, tailwind-css

This is my react code i want to use tailwind propeties here i already install tailwind during installing of react font-bold property work other propeties doesn't work like text-xl **HERE IS MY CODE **

```
import React from 'react'


const page = () => {


  return (

    <>

    <div className='text-xl font-bold'>Ikram khan</div>

    </>

    )

}

export default page
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.